# Why R ggplot2 geom_text is under geom_point and geom_line with this code?

Tags: r, ggplot2

My code is as follows:

```
p <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, group = Species, color = Species)) +
    geom_text(aes(y = Petal.Length, x = Sepal.Length, label = Petal.Length), inherit.aes = FALSE) +
    geom_line(size = 1.25) +
    geom_point(size = 2.25) +
    
    theme_bw(base_size = 14) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1), legend.position = "right") + 
    scale_x_discrete(breaks = waiver())
  
  p <- p + scale_y_continuous(trans='log10',
                                               breaks=trans_breaks('log10', function(x) 10^x),
                                               labels=trans_format('log10', math_format(10^.x)) ) + ylab("Petal.Length (logarithmic scale)")
  
p
```

And the output is as follows:
[image]

Now, I would like to brought the geom_text to the front. It is not very useful, to have it behind geom_point and geom_line, is it? :)

So what have I understood and done wrong? :)

Comment: Move `geom_text` to after `geom_point`. Like this `ggplot` draws the text first, then the lines and finally the points. The behavior you are seeing is expected.

Comment: @RuiBarradas , thank you. This was easier and more logical than I thought! :D

Answer (score 0):

Uses the ggrepel package to make sure that the text does not overlay the graphic elements.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggrepel/vignettes/ggrepel.html

Have a nice day.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).